# getting error while trying to insert in mysql using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, javabeans

hi i want to insert into the database few field names and for that i am using java bean,jsp and servlet but i am getting the error.I tried using preparedStatement then i tried using Statement but in both the cases i am getting error>please point out where is the error.My code is as follows.I am using eclipse juno IDE

register1.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

import DB.DataBaseConnection;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class register
 */
@WebServlet(register1.REGISTER1)
public class register1 extends HttpServlet {
    static final String REGISTER1 = "/register1";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public register1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        try{
        DataBaseConnection db=new DataBaseConnection();
        java.sql.Connection con= db.connet();
        String FirstName=request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String LastName=request.getParameter("LastName");
        String DOB=request.getParameter("DOB");
        String Qualification=request.getParameter("Qualification");
        String RegistrationNo=request.getParameter("RegistrationNo");
        String CountryOfRegistration=request.getParameter("CountryOfRegistration");
        String PracticeName=request.getParameter("PracticeName");
        String Phone=request.getParameter("Phone");
        String Email=request.getParameter("Email");
        String Address=request.getParameter("Address");
        String Street=request.getParameter("Street");
        String City=request.getParameter("City");
        String State=request.getParameter("State");
        String Country=request.getParameter("Country");
        String PinCode=request.getParameter("PinCode");
        String HowDoYouKnow=request.getParameter("HowDoYouKnow");
        String Comments=request.getParameter("Comments");


out.println(FirstName);







        //ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?)");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("insert into registration values(v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v)");
//      PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
//      out.println(FirstName);
//
//  ps.setString(1, FirstName);
//  out.println(FirstName);
//
//  ps.setString(2,LastName);
//  ps.setString(3,DOB);
//  out.println(FirstName);
//
//  ps.setString(4,Qualification);
//  ps.setString(5, RegistrationNo);
//  ps.setString(6, CountryOfRegistration);
//  ps.setString(7, PracticeName);
//  ps.setString(8, Phone);
//  ps.setString(9, Email);
//  ps.setString(10, Address);
//  ps.setString(11, Street);
//  ps.setString(12, City);
//  ps.setString(13, State);
//  ps.setString(14, Country);
//  ps.setString(15, PinCode);
//  ps.setString(16, HowDoYouKnow);
//  ps.setString(17, Comments);
//  ps.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

javabean

```
package register;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

import DB.DataBaseConnection;
public class registration {


        private String FirstName;
        private String LastName;
        private String DOB;
        private String Qualification;
        private String RegistrationNo;
        private String CountryOfRegistration;
        private String PracticeName;
        private String Phone;
        private String Email;
        private String Address;
        private String Street;
        private String City;
        private String State;
        private String Country;
        private String PinCode;
        private String HowDoYouKnow;
        private String Comments;
        public registration()
        {
            this.FirstName=FirstName;
            this.LastName=LastName;
            this.DOB=DOB;
            this.Qualification=Qualification;
            this.RegistrationNo=RegistrationNo;
            this.CountryOfRegistration=CountryOfRegistration;
            this.PracticeName=PracticeName;
            this.Phone=Phone;
            this.Email=Email;
            this.Address=Address;
            this.Street=Street;
            this.City=City;
            this.State=State;
            this.Country=Country;this.PinCode=PinCode;this.HowDoYouKnow=HowDoYouKnow;   
            this.Comments=Comments;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String FirstName)
        {
            this.FirstName=FirstName;
        }
        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return FirstName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String LastName)
        {
            this.LastName=LastName;
        }
        public String getLastName()
        {
            return LastName;
        }public void setDOB(String DOB)
        {
            this.DOB=DOB;
        }
        public String getDOB()
        {
            return DOB;
        }public void setQualification(String Qualification)
        {
            this.Qualification=Qualification;
        }
        public String getQualification()
        {
            return Qualification;
        }public void setRegistrationNo(String RegistrationNo)
        {
            this.RegistrationNo=RegistrationNo;
        }
        public String getRegistrationNo()
        {
            return RegistrationNo;
        }public void setCountryOfRegistration(String CountryOfRegistration)
        {
            this.CountryOfRegistration=CountryOfRegistration;
        }
        public String getCountryOfRegistration()
        {
            return CountryOfRegistration;
        }public void setPracticeName(String PracticeName)
        {
            this.PracticeName=PracticeName;
        }
        public String getPracticeName()
        {
            return PracticeName;
        }public void setPhone(String Phone)
        {
            this.Phone=Phone;
        }
        public String getPhone()
        {
            return Phone;
        }public void setEmail(String Email)
        {
            this.Email=Email;
        }
        public String getEmail()
        {
            return Email;
        }public void setAddress(String Address)
        {
            this.Address=Address;
        }
        public String getAddress()
        {
            return Address;
        }public void setStreet(String Street)
        {
            this.Street=Street;
        }
        public String getStreet()
        {
            return Street;
        }public void setCity(String City)
        {
            this.City=City;
        }
        public String getCity()
        {
            return City;
        }public void setState(String State)
        {
            this.State=State;
        }
        public String getState()
        {
            return State;
        }public void setCountry(String Country)
        {
            this.Country=Country;
        }
        public String getCountry()
        {
            return Country;
        }public void setPinCode(String PinCode)
        {
            this.PinCode=PinCode;
        }
        public String getPinCode()
        {
            return PinCode;
        }public void setHowDoYouKnow(String HowDoYouKnow)
        {
            this.HowDoYouKnow=HowDoYouKnow;
        }
        public String getHowDoYouKnow()
        {
            return HowDoYouKnow;
        }public void setComments(String Comments)
        {
            this.Comments=Comments;
        }
        public String getComments()
        {
            return Comments;
        }
        public String insert() throws ClassNotFoundException 
        {
            String output="";
        //public void insert(String FirstName,String LastName,String DOB) throws SQLException
        //{
        //DataBaseConnection db= new DataBaseConnection();
        //Connection con =(Connection) db.connet();
        //PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        //PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","sukanth","");
            //ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?)");
            PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, FirstName);
        ps.setString(2,LastName);
        ps.setString(3,DOB);

        ps.setString(4,Qualification);
        ps.setString(5, RegistrationNo);
        ps.setString(6, CountryOfRegistration);
        ps.setString(7, PracticeName);
        ps.setString(8, Phone);
        ps.setString(9, Email);
        ps.setString(10, Address);
        ps.setString(11, Street);
        ps.setString(12, City);
        ps.setString(13, State);
        ps.setString(14, Country);
        ps.setString(15, PinCode);
        ps.setString(16, HowDoYouKnow);
        ps.setString(17, Comments);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        output="sucess";

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            output=e.toString();
        }
        /*public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
        {
            registration r=new registration();
            r.insert("s","k","n");
        }*/
        return output;
    }
//      public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
//      {
//          registration r=new registration();
//          r.insert();
//      }

}
```

datas are taken from this jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><jsp:useBean id="registration" class="register.registration" scope="request">
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="registration"/></jsp:useBean>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action ="register1" method="post">
FirstName<input type="text" name="FirstName">Lastname<input type="text" name="LastName"><br>
DOB<input type="text" name="DOB">Qualification<input type="text" name="Qualification"><br>
RegistrationNo<input type="text" name="RegistrationNo">CountryOfRegistration<input type="text" name="CountryOfRegistration"><br>
PracticeName<input type="text" name="PracticeName">Phone<input type="text" name="Phone"><br>
Email<input type="text" name="Email">Address<input type="text" name="Address"><br>
Street<input type="text" name="Street">City<input type="text" name="City"><br>
State<input type="text" name="State">Country<input type="text" name="Country"><br>
PinCode<input type="text" name="PinCode">HowDoYouKnow<input type="text" name="HowDoYouKnow"><br>
Comments<input type="text" name="Comments"><br>
<input type ="submit" name ="submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the error

```
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:project1' did not find a matching property.
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:project2' did not find a matching property.
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:project3' did not find a matching property.
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2844 ms
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:55 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [117] milliseconds.
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2013 5:48:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1493 ms
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at register1.doPost(register1.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at register1.doPost(register1.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at register1.doPost(register1.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at register1.doPost(register1.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

this is the DataBaseConnection class

```
package DB;
import  java.sql.*;
public class  DataBaseConnection
{public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {

    DataBaseConnection db= new DataBaseConnection();
    Connection  con=db.connet();
        if(!con.isClosed())
        {
            System.out.println("connectedn");
        }
        }
public Connection connet() 
{
    Connection con=null;

    try
    {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","sukanth","");
return con;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return  con;
    }



}
}
```

Comment: Its clearly says to check Line No 77 At `register1.java`. Did you try to debug there ?

Comment: @HardikMishra i tried but could not solve it

Comment: @HardikMishra earlier it was showing error for preparedStatement so i changed to statement. If i use main for testing purpose then datas get inserted into the table ,you can see it i have commented the main.

Comment: `con` object might be null. Make sure that you are getting connected to the database.

Comment: I think you simply mixed up the code. You put the connection and insertion related logic in your registration class, then what is there in DataBaseConnection class and what is its role? You are not clear with this code. Whatever registration class insetrt() method is doing the same you are doing in doPost(-,-) method of your servlet.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena DataBaseConnection is class to connect to the mysql.Earlier i was trying with calling this object but getting error,so instead of calling the DataBaseConnection Object i tried with con.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli i have checked ,con is not null

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena this is the DatabaseConnection class

package DB;
import  java.sql.*;
public class  DataBaseConnection
{public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
 {
  
 DataBaseConnection db= new DataBaseConnection();
 Connection con=db.connet();
  if(!con.isClosed())
  {
   System.out.println("connectedn");
  }
  }
public Connection connet() 
{
 Connection con=null;
 try
 {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","sukanth","");
return con;
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  return  con;
 }
}
}

Comment: @javaL: You can edit post to add more details. Also, Keep relevant information only when asking a question.

Comment: Why are you returning `return  con;` from `catch` block. It may return NULL if you get exception while creating Connection.

Comment: @HardikMishra databaseConnection class is not used here,so if con is null also then it wont create any problem, by the way before implementing i have checked using main and it works fine

Comment: As best of my knowledge main(-) method is not supposed to be put in a web application related logic as main method is called by JRE/JVM while executing desktop applications/stand alone programs. I am not sure about "what and why you are doing?"

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena see i am using main method to check if the code is correct or not.if it works perfeclty then i remove the main and post in the web Apllication. if i get any errors then i fix it,so i use main method,Now u understand for what purpose i use main

Comment: Simply for checking your errors/exceptions in any web resource you should use printStackTrace() method over Exception reference or use exception inbuilt object in JSP, SOP's to get the point/location of error/exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at register1.doPost(register1.java:77)
```

The error clearly suggests `NullPointerException` at

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        try{
        DataBaseConnection db=new DataBaseConnection();
        java.sql.Connection con= db.connet();
        //...... 
       //Statement st=con.createStatement(); // This may be the root cause of exception
       // check null here
      if(con!=null){
        // create statement or prepared statement
      }  
}
```

Modified DataBaseConnection.java

```
package DB;
import java.sql.*;
public class DataBaseConnection {
    public Connection connet() {
        Connection con=null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","sukanth","");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you have `mysqljdbc.jar` in your CLASSPATH. Copy `mysqljdbc.jar` at `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: No. You have edited my answer to post stacktrace. Edit question.

Comment: to show you the error i edit the question,i know this is not the right way,sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the `Class.forName()` to load the driver in your Register1.java

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","sukanth","");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
//remaining codes
```

Make sure you are providing all the values in JSP page. And also make sure the DOB field in your database is string, if not convert the DOB filed in your servlet to Date format

Comment: OP is creating Db connection from a class called `DataBaseConnection` which has `Class.forName()`

Comment: oh. I didn't see that. He has put the statement with `getParameter` statements.

Comment: Since he is using `statement`, he has to pass all the values in the query itself right? And also he has to provide all the values, otherwise it will show `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

`I think you simply mixed up the code. 
You put the connection and insertion related logic in your`registration class`, then what is there in DataBaseConnection class and what is its role? You are not clear with this code. Whatever`registration class insetrt()`method is doing the same you are doing in`doPost(-,-)` method of your servlet.

I think no need of taking bean class for setting and getting form components values.
    Simply take a bean class that contains two methods one for making DB connection and second for releasing the connection.
Create its object in servlet's doGet(-,-) method and read all the form components values as you did by using request.getParameter(-) 
and set those values to your query's placeholders by using pstmnt.setXxx() and simply execute your query.
After successful execution call the second method on bean class to release the connection.

try this, I hope it will be helpfull...

```
    //write a bean class in some package(p1)
    package p1;
    //import all required classes/interfaces
    public class DBConn{
    private Connection con;
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host_ipaddress:port no./sid","username","password");
    return con;
    }

    public void releaseConnection() throws SQLException{

     if(con!=null)
     con.close();
      }
    }

//Take a form page(jsp/html) same as you have....

//write a servlet to insert the form page data in DB..


//import all classes and interfaces here...
public class register1 extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  try{  
        // set content type and get an output stream...      
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        //create bean class object and get a connection object...
        DBConn db=new DBConn();
        java.sql.Connection con= db.getConnection();

        // read all request parameter values from request...
        String FirstName=request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String LastName=request.getParameter("LastName");
        String DOB=request.getParameter("DOB");
        String Qualification=request.getParameter("Qualification");
        String RegistrationNo=request.getParameter("RegistrationNo");
        String CountryOfRegistration=request.getParameter("CountryOfRegistration");
        String PracticeName=request.getParameter("PracticeName");
        String Phone=request.getParameter("Phone");
        String Email=request.getParameter("Email");
        String Address=request.getParameter("Address");
        String Street=request.getParameter("Street");
        String City=request.getParameter("City");
        String State=request.getParameter("State");
        String Country=request.getParameter("Country");
        String PinCode=request.getParameter("PinCode");
        String HowDoYouKnow=request.getParameter("HowDoYouKnow");
        String Comments=request.getParameter("Comments");

        // get a pre-compiled query with the help of PreparedStatement ...
        PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement("insert into <table name>
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

   //set the place holder parameters values to the pre-compiled query..
    ps.setString(1, FirstName);
    ps.setString(2,LastName);
    ps.setString(3,DOB);
    ps.setString(4,Qualification);
    ps.setString(5, RegistrationNo);
    ps.setString(6, CountryOfRegistration);
    ps.setString(7, PracticeName);
    ps.setString(8, Phone);
    ps.setString(9, Email);
    ps.setString(10, Address);
    ps.setString(11, Street);
    ps.setString(12, City);
    ps.setString(13, State);
    ps.setString(14, Country);
    ps.setString(15, PinCode);
    ps.setString(16, HowDoYouKnow);
    ps.setString(17, Comments);
  int counter= ps.executeUpdate();

    if(counter>0)
    {
     out.println("Values inserted successfully...");
    db.releaseConnection();
    }
  else if(counter<=0)
   {
    out.println("Something went wrong, Values couldn't inserted in DB..");
    db.releaseConnection();
   }

    }
    catch(SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
   catch(ServletException se)
   {
   se.printStackTrace();
    }
   catch(IOException ie)
   {
    ie.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }//doGet(-,-) closing.....

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     doGet(request,response);
    }//doPost(-,-) closing...
}// servlet class closing...
```

// don't forget to map your servlet with a URL and use the same on your form page as action value of your form tag, and MYSQL related Connector/J jar file in class path and lib folder of your application or server's lib folder(Better if you put it in your application's lib folder).
    Hope it w'ld be clear to you.

Comment: i am not using java bean right now and the flow is from login.html ->jsp->servlet

Comment: databasesconnection is not having any role now,so i have commented it

Comment: should i remove the javabean because it creating confusion?

Comment: Ok I can do one thing, I am adding another answer and will try to put all logic for you, give me just 15 min. as I am busy with some other stuffs.

Comment: i could not understand your posted answer.Can you please post the code here. you know the flow as well as you have my codes.Please edit the same and post here. I would be very glad if you do so

Comment: I edited and placed the code here in my previous answer. Just check it.

Comment: i did as you said and i am getting the same error. If you want then i can send you the codes as well

Comment: edit your question and remove old code. put your code and error message too.

Comment: sorry to say that now i do not have the code now because i have edited it but still i am wondering for the answer.i know its not right to ask for the full code but i still need it. please post the full code

Comment: i wanted to use MVC pattern because it is the best way.if possible please do it in the same way

Comment: @javaL : you can not expect spoon feeding here. But still I wanna help you because in starting days of my career sometimes I realized someone's help may give you a right direction. Would you like to do it in struts or spring? give me your mail id if possible. I will send it to you.

Comment: sorry for asking but i need it very badly.i have to develop only using jsp,servlet,mysql,html,css,javascript. no use of struts/sprigs.this is my email is sukantnayak_nayak@yahoo.com. Hoping for the answer soon